# Python rss feed gets AttributeError

Tags: python, feedparser

Running this code:

```
import feedparser

Feed = feedparser.parse('http://www.reddit.com/r/python/.rss')
pointer = Feed.entries[1]
print (pointer.summary)
print (pointer.link)
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'feedparser' has no attribute '__version__' (most likely due to a circular import)

I'm using Idle on a Mac, but I get the same error running in Terminal.

Comment: Do you have your own file named `feedparser.py`? Don't use the same name as a library module.

Comment: filename is rss_feed.py

Comment: If that were the problem it would say that it can't find the library.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your symptom.

Using feedparser 6.0.10 under cPython 3.10.8 and macos 12.6.2 your 1st print says:

```
<!-- SC_OFF --><div class="md"><p>Discussion of using Python in a professional environment, getting jobs in Python as well as ask questions about courses to further your python education!</p> <p><strong>This thread is not for recruitment, please see</strong> <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/PythonJobs">r/PythonJobs</a> <strong>or the thread in the sidebar for that.</strong></p> </div><!-- SC_ON --> &#32; submitted by &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Im__Joseph"> /u/Im__Joseph </a> <br /> <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/109k9to/thursday_daily_thread_python_careers_courses_and/">[link]</a></span> &#32; <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/109k9to/thursday_daily_thread_python_careers_courses_and/">[comments]</a></span>
```

and your 2nd print says

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/109k9to/thursday_daily_thread_python_careers_courses_and/
```

---

Use `$ python -m site` to verify that `sys.path`
points to where you think it should,
and that you've installed just a single feedparser
library there. Consider nuking your venv and
doing pip installs from scratch.

It is possible that you showed us just an excerpt
from a larger codebase. Read your posted question
and try to reproduce the symptom -- copy-n-paste
those few lines of code into a new file and run that.
Or use example code from
[the docs](https://feedparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html),
which is very similar.
It sounds like your install can't even support
`$ python -c 'import feedparser'` yet.

Comment: I get same AttributeError error even if the only line in the file is "import feedparser".  But when I enter import feedparser directly into  the Idle shell, there's no error. Although entering other lines of the code result in assorted errors. If I enter Feed.keys(), I get the following output:
 dict_keys(['bozo', 'entries', 'feed', 'headers', 'bozo_exception'])

Comment: You have two environments where you're using feedparser: IDE and command line. One of them is working. We want to know what's different about them, so we can fix the broken one. Are you running the _same_ interpreter in each? If `.` dot is in your PYTHONPATH env var, then the value of `os.getcwd()` is relevant. And `sys.path` controls the behavior of `import`. In each environment, write `sys.path` out to a text file. Compare those files, perhaps using `$ diff -u`. [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your analysis.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how to compare the two environments? I'm not very experienced with this stuff. My pip install of feedparser was through the correct file path to where Idle is installed on my Mac. I have installed numerous other libraries to Idle with no problems like this. I'm running Python 3.10.2 in Idle. Is there a way to determine which version of feedparser is installed?

Comment: Did you nuke your venv and pip install it again from scratch?

Comment: Start with `$ which python` to understand where the interpreter is coming from. Often there's more than one interpreter, each with its own set of installed importable libraries. I reported this triple to you: (feedparser 6.0.10, cPython 3.10.8, macos 12.6.2). Report the same triple for both environments, one working and one broken. I used conda with the pip install, so I obtained "6.0.10" from `$ conda list | grep feedparser`. Sometimes I will use poetry: `$ poetry show | grep ...`. Maybe you're looking for `$ pip list | grep ...`. Verify that .../python3.10/site-packages has what you expect.

Comment: Phew, I don't know how to "nuke my venv" but I was looking around to see where feedparser is installed, and found an earlier effort of this code, entitled feedparser.py. I deleted that and the script now runs without the AttriubuteError.  The line: pointer = Feed.entries[1] gives me an index out of range error, but at least I'm in the ballpark. Thanks for the help!